# LinkedIn API to get 3rd degree connections

Tags: linkedin-api

Can we get the 3rd degree connection using LinkedIn API.

using the people API call I am only getting the list of 1st degree connection but i need to get the 2nd and 3rd degree contact information.

- I read somewhere that we can first get the information about the first degree connection and  take the Ids of the first degree connections and again make a call to the people API with each of the Ids. The problem I am facing it, It always returns me the record in the context of the logged in user. I mean the relationship-to-viewer is not in the context of the Id that we passed, it is still in the context of logged in user. Please help I am stuck.
- Is it possible to get the 3rd degree connection information if I upgrade my account to premium account.
- Is there any other way, has anybody ever done this.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question: yes, if you upgrade to LinkedIn premium. You will be able to "view unlimited profiles from search results – up to 3rd degree". They have a one-month free trial now.

Answer (score 0):

From [linkedin API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api)

> You cannot "browse connections." That is, you can only get the
>   connections of the user who granted your application access. **You
>   cannot get connections of that user's connections (2nd degree
>   connections)**